# (WordPress) How do I center galleries?

Tags: css, wordpress, gallery

I've recently changed my blog's theme and this new theme didn't center galleries at all until I managed to fix this with some CSS. However, there's still a problem with the last row if it doesn't have as many images as previous ones. (example: https://blog.ovidiuav.com/2018/11/09/nou-autor-blog/)

As you can see in the example, I inserted a 3-column gallery with 2 rows, but the last row only has two images. I would like the last row to center the images so it looks nicer. So whenever the last row has fewer images, I would like them centered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like the way it is. But if you really must, use flexbox (or grid):

```
#gallery-1 {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery-item {
   flex-basis: 33%;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! I didn't like it because it just looked incomplete, like the last image was missing.

Maybe you can help me with something else? As you can see, the hyperlinks exceed the images (for example you can open images even when clicking between them, or if I have a gallery with only one image, the hyperlink extends both left and right of the image for the whole length of the content). Do you know how I could only have the images themselves be clickable?

Thank you!

Comment: You have to think of how to build the DOM. Basically you need to put the border around the image on the element outside of the anchor tag. Cheers!